# Method/Functions as Bindings Constantly Being Called / Angular 6-CLI

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

In my component.html, I have something simple:

```
<div [class.inactive]="getClass()"></div>
```

And in the .TS, I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MessageService} from 'primeng/api';
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { 
   ...
  }
   ...
  getClass() : string {
    console.log("getClass");
    return "jason"
  }
  ..
}
```

When I run this (Angular CLI / 6), and open up the developer console window - it's spitting out "getClass" a **lot** and non-stop.    If I do nothing, maybe 2-3 every 3 seconds - and if I wiggle the mouse or click around, it spams it to high-heaven.

Is this normal behavior?   I would think it'd only call it once, or maybe if the backing observable (if there was one) changed.

It's the same if I set something like a SELECT or PrimeNG dropdown source data as a method/function:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="getEarlyBirdRates()">
```

If I put a console.log in `getEarlyBirdRates` I see it being called just as frequently, and for no discernable reason.

Am I not allowed to bind this way?

Comment: Yes, this is normal behaviour. It is run on every change detection cycle. Instead, call `getClass` in `ngOnInit`, and store the result in a variable and bind to that instead

Comment: What if this data is from a service (the service holds the array of objects) - if I copy it to a local variable, I lose the ability to pick up any changes at the source, if they have any, yes?    Is this where I'd set up BehaviorSubject and subscribe to changes at the service's level?

Comment: When you say changes at the source, what do you mean? What type of data are you dealing with? Is the data an Observable, an object, an array, etc.

Comment: I have an array of a custom object in a service.   In separate components on the page, they're showing a subset of these objects - based on a property in the object (ie.,  getEarlyBirdRates is   myService.rates.filter(x=>x.RateType='Early')   )   -- other components show different views into the master "rate" array.     If a change happens to the array, I'd like components to know about it, to update their list if necessary.   This way now *works* but - as I said, spammy as all heck, for no apparent reason.

Comment: So really, it depends. If a change happens *inside* that array, then you will get that update, because the array is passed by reference. If the array is reassigned inside the service, you will not get that update

Comment: OK, I'll give your suggestion a whirl and see where it takes me.  Thanks, Mr. 184994. =)